# Is there a web interface for apt packages without access to a machine running apt?

Tags: apt, package-management, synaptic

Note: This is definitely **not** a duplicate of [Is there an online/web interface to search and list apt-get packages and see summaries and recommendations?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98164/is-there-an-online-web-interface-to-search-and-list-apt-get-packages-and-see-sum#98165) because this has different constraints.

I'm writing the provisioning for some Ubuntu based boxes right now. Instead of working out which VM is running what and booting one up or (whatever myriad container might have one) and using the CLI, **is there a web interface I can search** ***without the need to have apt available***?

I'm not interested in Snap or any other package manager's packages, just those that apt/synaptic would install.

Any help with this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu has a [package search](https://packages.ubuntu.com) site which provides information on all the packages available from Ubuntu repositories, and only those, for all the currently-supported releases. That’s all the packages you’d be able to install using APT or Synaptic in a standard Ubuntu setup.